# Redirect jpg using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to use htaccess to redirect all images in jpgs like www.domain.com/94-56-name.jpg to www.domain.com/name.jpg. Have tried a few rules but not working as it should.

The code I came across pertains to folder redirect and was not able to replicate these for me. Moreover I would like an internal redirect (i.e without mentioning the domain names)

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^static/images\/(.*\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg))?$ assets/upload/subfolder/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot help with your code if you do not post your code.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem.StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Apart from that it is unclear what you actually try to do. Your question needs to be phrased more precise: which if the two URLs you mention is actually requested by clients, to which should that get rewritten internally?